# Get specific region of canvas in android

Tags: android, canvas

I am using canvas in android and i have drew a circle with four partitions in center of screen and with radius 300

I am blocked how to get only first potion of arc in circle and fill that or manipulate progratically , i dont want to redraw above it instead what user has drew in first arc i want that region and repaint it in some other area

I tried with getting computeBounds but then it gives me region out of first arc also

I just need closed boundry region of first arc in circle whose has 4 arcs means 4 partitions

Any help or hints would be appreciated

Comment: You can draw arc and fill it with different color with the help of different paint objects  is that make sense below i posted some sample codes

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CircleView extends View {

    Paint paint,paint1,paint2,paint3;

    public CircleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CircleView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint1 = new Paint();
        paint1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint2 = new Paint();
        paint2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        paint3 = new Paint();
        paint3.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);


    }

    public CircleView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CircleView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        RectF rectF = new RectF();
        rectF.set(50,20,900,480);
       // canvas.drawArc (rectF, 90, 45, true, paint);
       // canvas.drawArc (rectF, 180, 90, true, paint1);


        canvas.drawArc(rectF, 135, 180, false, paint);
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, 135, 180 - 1, false,paint1);
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, 90, 180+ 1, false,paint2);
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, 90, 180, false, paint3);
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, 45, 180, false, paint);


    }


}
```